# ReactNative - How to call function in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I'm new to ReactNative and I'm trying Integrate React Native to my current project.

In my ViewController contain RCTRootView and the code implemented like:

**ViewController.swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    .....
        let bridge = RCTBridge(bundleURL: jsCodeLocation, moduleProvider: nil, launchOptions: nil)

        let reactRootView = RCTRootView(bridge: bridge, moduleName: "Index", initialProperties: props)

        self.view.addSubview(reactRootView);
        reactRootView.frame = self.view.bounds
        reactRootView.delegate = self;
    ....     
}

func onReactEvent(event :NSDictionary , callback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) {}
```

**ReactNativeManager.swift**

```
@objc func sendCustomEventToHost(event: NSDictionary, callback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) -> Void {}
```

So how can I call **onReactEvent()** function in my **ViewController** from function **sendCustomEventToHost()** in **ReactNativeManager**.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know how to passing my ViewController to ReactNativeManager using **launchOptions**

**ViewController.swift**

```
let bridge = RCTBridge(bundleURL: jsCodeLocation, moduleProvider: nil, launchOptions: ["controller":self"])
```

Access from 
**ReactNativeManager.swift**

```
let controller = self.bridge.launchOptions["controller"]
```

Hope this help!!

Answer (score 0):

In `ReactNativeManager` you have to create an instance of ViewController.
 For example:

```
let viewC = ViewController()
```

and then you just call:

```
viewC.onReactEvent(....)
```

Comment: Because I want to use some variables in the ViewController which is initialised before. 
The code "let viewC = ViewController()" will init the new one have different address.
I don't know how to call the method of the parent ViewController which contain RCTRootView

Comment: ReactNativeManager is pushed from ViewController?

Comment: ReactNativeManager class inherit from RCTBridgeModule, Initiated and its methods are called by React Native view.